# How to return an array of double values from the strings?

Tags: java

I would like to return an  array   of  double  values  from    the strings. How can I do that? I have been unable to do it with the following....

```
public static double[] fillArray(String numbers)
{
    String[] answers = numbers.split(",");


    double[] boom = new double[answers];

    for (int index = 0; index < answers.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(answers[index]);
    }

    return boom;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to use `length` to get the length of the array.

```
double[] boom = new double[answers.length];
```

Then, inside the loop, convert the `String` into `double`.

```
boom[index] = Double.parseDouble(answers[index]);
```

Finally, use `try-catch` or throw `exception` from method for the `parseDouble()`

Answer (score 2):

First of all `double[] boom = new double[answers]` doesn't make sense, since `answers` is an array. You want to do:

```
double[] boom = new double[answers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; ++i) {
  boom[i] = Double.valueOf(answers[i]);
}
```

in which you use [`Double.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the String to a `double`. Mind that the method could raise a `NumberFormatException` in case the string couldn't be parsed to a double.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you will be soon able to do this in one line using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

```
public static double[] fillArray(String numbers){
     return Arrays.stream(numbers.split(","))
                  .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                  .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert each String to a double.

Which you can do with the `Double(String s)` constructor or  `parseDouble(String s)`

```
public static double[] fillArray(String numbers)
{
    double[] boom = new double[answer.length];
    String[] answers = numbers.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
       boom[i] = Double.parseDouble(answers[i]);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < answers.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(answers[index]);
    }

    return boom;
}
```